# Как зарегистрировать два post type в вордпрессе?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как зарегистрировать два и более пост тайпа в вордпрессе.
Сейчас делаю таким образом

```
add_action( 'init', 'osk_lex__ur_uslugi' );

function osk_lex__ur_uslugi() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Услуги юрлицам', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Услуги юрлицам', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'услуги-юрлицам' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-filter',
        'supports'           => array( 'title')
    );

    register_post_type( 'услуги-юрлица', $args );
}
```

Данный код регистрирует пост тайп, однако, если я регистрирую второй пост тайп, первый не регистрируется. Получается, что второй код перезаписывает первый.

```
add_action( 'init', 'osk_lex__fiz_uslugi' );

function osk_lex__fiz_uslugi() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Услуги физлицам', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Услуги физлицам', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'услуги-физлицам' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title')
    );

    register_post_type( 'услуги-физлицам', $args );
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте создание обоих типов в одну функцию

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'osk_lex__ur_uslugi' );

function osk_lex__ur_uslugi() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'          => _x( 'Услуги юрлицам', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Услуги юрлицам', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'услуги-юрлицам' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-filter',
        'supports'           => array( 'title' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'uslugi-yur', $args );

    $labels = array(
        'name'          => _x( 'Услуги физлицам', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Услуги физлицам', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'услуги-физлицам' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'uslugi-fiz', $args );
}
```

P.S. Надо только заменить типы постов в `register_post_type()` на английские. В функции `register_post_type()` идёт вызов `sanitize_key( $post_type )`, которая оставляет в имени типа поста только английские буквы, цифры, `_` и `-`. Поэтому в вашем случае оба названия типа поста приводились к одному символу `-` и вторая регистрация перекрывала первую.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, попробовал сделать так как вы говорите, однако все равно не помогло. по прежнему выводит код который идет ниже

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Я не обратил внимания на то, что у вас русские буквы в типе поста. Пояснил, что происходило с вашим кодом, почему вторая регистрация перекрывала первую.

Comment: @KAGG Design не понял Единственный обладатель значков: серебряный WordPress и WooCommerce на StackOverflow RU. хотя у Вас бронзовый знак по WooCommerce

Comment: @Leks всё правильно написано. Если бы было написано "единственный обладатель серебряных значков: WordPress и WooCommerce", то претензия была бы обоснована.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали на другом форуме, оказывается ошибка была в регистрации русскими буквами, нужно регистрировать кириллицей. Может кому то пригодится.

Comment: Кириллица и русские буквы - это одно и то же)